# SHAP is not working with CatBoost categorical features

Tags: python, machine-learning, shap, catboost

I encountered a problem with categorical features while training the CatBoost model.

```
CatBoostError: Bad value for num_feature[non_default_doc_idx=0,feature_idx=23]="100+ доступны после заявки на подключение": Cannot convert 'b'100+ \xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x83\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f\xd0\xb2\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xba\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8e\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5'' to float
```

Then I used Pool and it worked:

```
chunk_pool = Pool(chunk_df[all_features], cat_features=cat_features)
chunk_df[f'score_{channel}'] = cb_box_model_wt_p_av.predict_proba(chunk_pool)[:,1]
```

Instead of:

```
chunk_df[f'score_{channel}'] = cb_box_model.predict_proba(chunk_df[all_features])[:,1]
```

But then I tried to calculate SHAP and again problem appeared.

```
import shap

explainer = shap.Explainer(cb_box_model_wt_p_av)
shap_values = explainer(df_sample[all_features])


TypeError: Cannot convert 'b'100+ \xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x83\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f\xd0\xb2\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xba\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8e\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5'' to float
```

I hoped that Pool process would work again:

```
chunk_pool_sample = Pool(df_sample[all_features], cat_features=cat_features)
explainer = shap.Explainer(cb_box_model_wt_p_av)
shap_values = explainer(chunk_pool_sample)
```

And the values were calculated but then I tried to create SHAP plots and got empty field:

```
shap.plots.beeswarm(shap_values, max_display=20)

TypeError: 'Pool' object is not subscriptable
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0ykO.png)

Then I wanted to understand what are the most important features in my model and tried this but also the problem occured:

```
feature_names = shap_values.feature_names
shap_df = pd.DataFrame(shap_values.values, columns=feature_names)
vals = np.abs(shap_df.values).mean(0)
shap_importance = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(feature_names, vals)), columns=['col_name', 'feature_importance_vals'])
shap_importance.sort_values(by=['feature_importance_vals'], ascending=False, inplace=True)\

TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

Is it possible to somehow fix those errors?

I expected to get plot like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xncua.png)

And the most important features:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwaIj.png)

Comment: Please [reprex]